# How to change the print size of a Word doc and scale everything proportionally?

Tags: ms-word

I have a Word doc in A4 size. I'd like to make it A3 size but everything should be scaled so that it looks identical proportionally. When I try to set the paper size, all the text and images stay the same size and therefore it changes the layout of the doc completely. Is there a way to do this easily or would I have to use a calculator to get the exact ratio to scale each element manually?

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums.